# Importing a React 16 component into an project using an extremely old React version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have project A which uses a very old version of React that isn't feasible to upgrade at this point (0.x) series, and project B which uses React 16.

These are in the same codebase, but are separated into directories, each with their own package.json - they aren't published an NPM modules.

The two projects are then built by Webpack into two bundles.

Now the problem is I'm trying to import a component located in project B (React 16) (by literally specifying the directory up a few levels into Project B) into the old project and it's resulting in nothing being rendered with no error. The issue seems to be the mismatch in React versions as when I change the component in Project B to use the old React version everything is fine.

What are the possible solutions to this?

I've read a couple of threads on here with similar issues, and the solution relates to peer dependencies but I'm not sure how this would work as they're not actually used as NPM components as such.

Cheers

Comment: Does the project A bundle include the old version of React?

Comment: In case you didn't already look at this when determining that an upgrade is infeasible, there are some code mods for doing upgrades: https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod

Comment: @Jacob Project A is the old React so it's included in the bundle, Project B's bundle just includes the newer 16.x React. Codemod is interesting but I'm time limited and the testing would take some time. Thanks for the reply!